# get value/innerHTML/text of item produced with css locator

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

I have something like:

```
var items=$$('some css location');
console.log(items.count());
console.log(items.get(3).getInnerHTML());
console.log(items.get(3).getAttribute('text'));
console.log(items.get(3).getText());
```

but all console.log calls return the objects itself with their functions,fields..
Is there a way to get the innerHTML/texts/values of the items without using `expect`? If I want to iterate the items and do some parsing over their values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the methods you call return [promises](https://www.promisejs.org/), so:

```js
items.count().then(function(value) {
    console.log(value);
});
```